# What is react-admin SearchInput searching for?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a data collection for `tags` which only has a `id` (string) field. I show it in a list.

[image]

Now I want to implement search function. Here is the code:

```
const TagFilter = (props) => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <SearchInput source="q" resettable alwaysOn />
  </Filter>
)

class TagList extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const props = this.props
    return (
      <List {...props} filters={<TagFilter />} sort={{ field: 'id', order: 'DESC' }} >
        <Datagrid>
          <ChipField label="Tag" source="id" />
        </Datagrid>
      </List>
    )
  }
}
```

But when I search for example: `mo`, the result is not found.

[image]

I'm wondering what is the `SearchInput` searching for? How to search my `id` field?

Answer (score 2):

Your `SearchInput` is searching a field named `"q"`. ([This is a JSON API thing](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest#making_a_request) to specify your search expression.)

Try changing the source in your filter to `"id"` like this:

```
const TagFilter = (props) => (
    <Filter {...props}>
        <SearchInput source="id" resettable alwaysOn />
    </Filter>
)
```

Comment: How can I search wild card, for example, when I key in `mo`, no result found. When I key in `movies`, there is one result.

Comment: That will depend on your database and how you've implemented the filtering in your API. You want to use something like `column.ilike()` instead of `column.is_()` which only does exact match.

Comment: Is able to change the react-admin implementation? How to change to `column.ilike` in react-admin?

Comment: React-Admin does not control how your API handles filters. When you make a GET request to your api it should have params like `{pagination: {page: 1, perPage: 10}, sort: {field: "id", order: "DESC"}, filter: {id: "mo"}}` It's up to you to modify your API to properly handle the `filter` param.

Comment: I see. I'm using Firebase. I noticed if my source is `title`, I can search in wildcard. But I have to key in exact work if my source is `id`.